# C# Array of instance of Class

Tags: c#, arrays, class

Here I'm trying to get the data for many employees that i predefined a class for it as This

```
public class Employee
{
    public int code;
    public float salary;
    public float bonus;
    public float deduction;
}
```

and i'm trying to make a function to create the array for the Employees and to ask the user to fill it

That's the code for now

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Task3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int size = 3;
            Employee[] E1 = GetEmployeeData(size);

        }

        static Colors GetIntFromUser(string Message)
        {
            int result;
            Console.Write(Message);
            result = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Colors c = (Colors)result;
            return c;
        }
        static Employee[] GetEmployeeData(int size)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                Employee[] E = new Employee [size];
                E[i] = new Employee();
                Console.Write("Code: ");
                E[i].code = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Salary: ");
                E[i].salary = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Bonus: ");
                E[i].bonus = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Deduction: ");
                E[i].deduction = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                return E[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i get that Error **Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0161  'Program.GetEmployeeData(int)': not all code paths return a value   Task3   E:\ITI39\Intro to programming\tasks\day5\ConsoleApplication1\Task3\Program.cs   26  Active**

and This one too  **Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'Task3.Employee' to 'Task3.Employee[]'   Task3   E:\ITI39\Intro to programming\tasks\day5\ConsoleApplication1\Task3\Program.cs   40  Active**

**P.S.** I don't Have Any OOP Experience more further i'm beginner in Programming

Comment: Your `GetEmployeeData` method doesn't make much sense. You are creating an array *inside* the `for` loop (meaning you create a new one on each iteration) and also trying to return a single instance with `return E[i];` (also inside the `for` loop, meaning you would only ever have a single iteration if this compiled)

Comment: Like @UnholySheep said you need to create the array outside of the loop, otherwise you are always discarding the old one. Your method signature states you return an Employee[], i.e. array of employees. However E[i] is just one employee. So obviously this doesn’t match. Thus you need to return E itself, also outside the array as otherwise you would return from the method in your first loop.

Comment: @UnholySheep i moved it outside the loop and the Errors still There

Comment: Move the return statement out of the bottom of the loop as well, the compiler isn't "smart enough" to understand whether it is guaranteed to run or not. Also, you probably want `return E;`

Comment: Thanks, Guys I made function return E and moved it outside the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error you are seeing is due to you only returning a value inside of the loop - if size were 0 then the loop would not execute and therefore no value would be returned.
The second error is due to you trying to return a single part of the array at the end of each loop. You need to return the whole array after the loop completes so rather than write

```
return E[i];
```

you should write

```
return E;
```

And this should be written after the loop ends, once you have received all 3 entries.

However there are other issues here as you create the 'E' variable each time the loop iterates and so you need to move the declaration of 'E' to be before the loop starts otherwise the result will only ever contain a valid object at index 2.
The entire corrected function would look like this:

```
static Employee[] GetEmployeeData(int size)
{
    Employee[] E = new Employee [size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        E[i] = new Employee();
        Console.Write("Code: ");
        E[i].code = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Salary: ");
        E[i].salary = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Bonus: ");
        E[i].bonus = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Deduction: ");
        E[i].deduction = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    return E;
}
```

You may also want to consider what would happen if the user was to enter a value that cannot be parsed to the type expected and defensively code for this - take a look at the TryParse function instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an Iterator and yield return the employees. This enables you to stream the results.

```
static IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployeeData(int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        Employee e = new Employee();
        Console.Write("Code: ");
        e.code = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Salary: ");
        e.salary = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Bonus: ");
        e.bonus = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Deduction: ");
        e.deduction = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        yield return e;
    }
}
```